# Oscillators-completely new approach

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator, oscillation, ham-radio

I found [this](https://www.qsl.net/va3iul/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics.htm) link about high frequency VCOs. Although I don't work with such high frequencies, I gave it a try. So I designed this circuit:

[image]

As you can see, I replaced BC547B (in previous post) transistor with BFP420 which has much lower BE capacitance. As the article suggests, I used C3 as small as possible to make it start, added L2 RF choke, increased C2 compared to C1, all that to increase quality. An article says that the circuit should have just enough gain to start because if gain is too high, quality decreases. So what do you think about my design?

Simulation results:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you make our lives a bit easier and tell us what frequency you're aiming at?

Comment: how do you build a circuit with 0.8 pF of capacitance? Because that's below what's typical for stray capacitances in discrete components, roughly an order of magnitude. Since that is a 10 GHz-rated transistor, you might be doing this as tightly controlled microscopic microwave device on low-epsilon substrate, then this might work. But then again I see an inductor of 100 nH, and that suggests we're rather talking about 1 MHz than 10 GHz, and it stops making sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller around 100 MHz probably. 0.8 pF is the lowest value that started oscillation in Multisim.

Comment: ah, so you have simulation results! So schare these! Again, you can't really buy and use a 0.8 pF capacitor, because in most technologies, parasitic effects are orders of magnitude larger. Were you able to ensure the V_CE of Q2 is within permissible ranges?

Comment: Can you indicate what article says that gain too high -> poor quality and what metrics "quality" means? Are you referring to phase noise? THD? Amplitude noise? In the integrated RF oscillator space, I've always set gain fairly high, giving faster startup, more swing (since gain compression happens a bit later), and strong swings, with good outcomes (phase noise being the metric we care about)

Comment: Im not impressed.At 100MHz  you can put a inductor,capacitor,resistor all parallel to each other charge the inductor with some current and provide a fairly stable oscillation(slightly damped).You dont need a Hartley oscillator.

Comment: @nanofarad https://www.qsl.net/va3iul/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics/High_Frequency_VCO_Design_and_Schematics.htm
under Parallel tuned colpitts VCO

Comment: @MissMulan The whole point of an *oscillator*, rather than a passive LCR, is that it's not a damped, *decaying* oscillation. The oscillator continues to run as long as it's supplied power. You can make that claim at any frequency, but the LCR does not meet the needs that an active oscillator meets.

Comment: @nanofarad If you make load 1kΩ and the capacitor 10mF the damping is in the order of e^-0.05t which means it will last  practically forever .

Comment: @MissMulan That's less than a few minutes, and you'd be hard-pressed to actually find components that are ideal enough to achieve such low loss. Regardless, explaining why this non-oscillator does not meet the needs of an oscillator is off-topic for a comment thread on active oscillators, which should be reserved for the question on hand.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added simulation results. The oscillation strength are so low that voltages don't really mind. As I have already said, I just used the lowest C3 capacitance to make it work, as it is written in an article above. However, simulation frequency doesn't seem to be very stable. Is it true that the lowest gain possible to make it start is the best because too high gain reduces Q?

Comment: For small loads <100Ω you can use a series RLC oscillator by charging the capacitor with some voltage and the damping factor can get as low as you want.

Comment: @PavleHribar Q is only half the story if you're concerned about a clean waveform free of phase noise. You ought to be maximizing the swing as well, which requires more gain (to account for the fact that gain may compress as you depart the operating point). [an aside, a series RLC resonator is still not an oscillator and isn't an on-topic suggestion for this conversation]

Comment: @nanofarad So what do you suggest to make tha highest Q possible? I now increased C3 to 10 pF, and it oscillates very well now, frequency seems to be very stable on 223.889 MHz, just waveform looks a little saturated. The frequency is much higher than I wanted, but since it's suggested to keep C3 as low as possible, it would maybe be better to increase total capacitance of C1/C2.

Comment: @PavleHribar I'm still trying to get a sense of why you want the highest Q - it's an internal parameter of the oscillator and not something you see at the output directly. You observe phase noise (a spectrum rather than a single numerical value), THD, swing, and other properties of the output signal - which do you care about for your application? I'm also very hesitant to talk about Q-factors until the parasitics (especially leakages, ESRs, etc), but these other observable output parameters still apply.

Comment: @nanofarad Ok ok, if not Q, then I want the frequency to be as stable and as quality as possible

Comment: @PavleHribar Then you're probably looking for phase noise; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeson%27s_equation applies. It does take into account the loaded Q-factor, but that's a function of how lossy your passive L/C feedback network turns out to be *in practice* (or in a simulation that includes resistive parasitics), as well as how stable your capacitors and inductors are in practice. I'd still increase gain+swing since that can help with increasing the \$P_s\$ term of that equation. However, because of the big unknown with parasitics I'm not quite sure how to put together a coherent answer.

Comment: @nanofarad I have a problem now. I increased R4 to 150 to reduce gain because output was a little saturated, now it's all very unstable and noisy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134664/discussion-between-nanofarad-and-pavle-hribar).

Comment: `So what do you think about my design?` - it's a common collector colpitts oscillator and as standard as they come.

Comment: Just a "problem". The scope picture seems to show that your "step" time analysis is too big ...

Answer (score 1):

If this can help you, here is a Clapp oscillator @ 440 MHz
Just change L1 to adjust frequency.

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip)

[image]